# High cost for a pagination query

Tags: mysql, pagination, sql-execution-plan

I have a pagination query which does range index scan on a large table:

```
create table t_dummy (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  field1 varchar(255) not null,
  updated_ts timestamp null default null,
  primary key (id),
  key idx_name (updated_ts)
```

The query looks like this:

```
select * from t_dummy a
where a.field1 = 'VALUE'
and (a.updated_ts > 'some time' or (a.updated_ts = 'some time' and a.id > x)
order by a.updated_ts, a.id
limit 100
```

The explain plan show large cost with `rows` value being very high, however, it is using all the right indexes and the execution seems fast. Can someone please tell whether this means the query is inefficient?

Comment: First of all i would like to mention it that the table you have created and the table you have referred are not the same. The question regarding cost of query why don't you use `a.updated_ts>='some time' and a.id>x`  one more thing that can help you to optimize your query is try removing the order by clause from the query. The order by clause is creating the overhead on the output of query as it first sorts the output based on `updated_ts` and then again performing the sort operation on `id`. Hope you get my point what i am trying to tell you.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mismatch. corrected. I like the and clause optimization as well. However i need the results to be sorted in that order.

Comment: on the second thought, that AND refactoring is incorrect @ShaktiK ;) thanks for replying thou

Comment: I think they meant the and refactoring to be like in my answer

Answer (score 2):

EXPLAIN can be misleading. It can report a high value for `rows`, despite the fact that [MySQL optimizes LIMIT queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html) to stop once enough rows have been found that satisfy your requested LIMIT (100 in your case).

The problem is, at the time the query does the EXPLAIN, it doesn't necessarily know how many rows it will have to examine to find at least 100 rows that satisfy the conditions in your WHERE clause.

So you can usually ignore the `rows` field of the EXPLAIN when you have a LIMIT query. It *probably* won't really have to examine so many rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Bill. That's pretty helpful

Answer (score 1):

If the execution is fast enough, don't worry about it.  If it is not, consider a `(field1,updated_ts)` index and/or changing your query to

```
and a.updated_ts >= 'some time' and (a.updated_ts > 'some time' or a.id > x)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Bill says, Explain cannot be trusted to take `LIMIT` into account.

The following will confirm that the query is touching only 100 rows:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

The `Handler_read%` values will probably add up to about 100.  There will probably be no `Handler_write%` values -- they would indicate the creation of a temp table.

A tip:  If you use `LIMIT 101`, you get the 100 rows to show, plus an indication of whether there are more rows.  This, with very low cost, avoids having a [Next] button that sometimes brings up a blank page.

My tips on the topic:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Comment: This is interesting, thanks, I was looking for something in addition to EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see actual costs. It is showing "Handler_read_next = 99", no `writes` in sight. The `rows` is roughly 40% of the total row count, but fast

Comment: @user3621726 - 99 "next" rows in addition to 1 "first" row.  The query is efficient, despite what `EXPLAIN` says.  The slowlog would also say something like "Rows accessed: 100"